# Razor intellisense not working with custom ASP.NET MVC build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I was able to create a custom build of ASP.NET MVC and use it in a web application, however, I can't seem to figure out how to get the Razor intellisense to work correctly.

If you follow the steps below, the Razor intellisense will only show WebPages info and nothing else (HTML helpers etc.).

I'm using VS 2012.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I cloned the latest [ASP.NET Web Stack](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)
2. Opened the `Runtime.sln` and built the solution
3. Created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET 4.0) web application
4. Deleted existing references for `System.Web.Mvc`, `System.Web.Razor`, `System.Web.WebPages`, `System.Web.WebPages.Razor`, `System.Web.WebPages.Deployment` and added references to the built assemblies in step #2.
5. In `~/Views/Web.config`, replaced `System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35` with just `System.Web.WebPages.Razor`
6. Also, replaced `System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35` with just `System.Web.Mvc`
7. Removed the following from the `web.config`

   ```
   <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemasmicrosoftcom:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for intellisense support in VS 2012 for views, as well as the right-click context menus for the controllers folder and views folder (shortcuts to add controller and add view) then you need to open up the .csproj file of your web project and manually edit it to include the MVC project type GUID. This is what VS actually uses to decide what flavor of intellisense you get (among other things).

Specifically, the xml tag of the .csproj file you're looking for is:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

You should be missing the GUID value

```
{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
```

Good luck!