# Intellisense does not working for Visual Studio project (SharePoint , Application Page)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, intellisense, applicationpage

I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 3. I created a SharePoint project which contains an application page. It has been working for a while. Today when I reopened the project the intellisense stoped working and generates this warning `Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp'`. All other projects have no problem

Comment: Does [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809653/unrecognized-tag-prefix-or-device-filter-asp-in-vs2012)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471887/visual-studio-2013-intellisense-stops-working-for-asp-net-mvc5-controllers 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063296/razor-intellisense-not-working-with-custom-asp-net-mvc-build

Comment: I have no web.config file because it is a SharePoint project and I am suing Application Pages.

Comment: When it comes to sharepoint do what I do.  Create a new asp.net web project for web forms.  Do all your work in there and test in local iis...  When finished, move it over to the sharepoint project, so much easier and more time effecient.  Sharepoint is a BEAST, you can spend weeks trying to get some nice to have feature to work, or you can just do it in what works now and only care if the code isn't doing what it should.